# NoSQL to SQL adapter design pattern

Tags: sql, node.js, design-patterns, nosql

I have 2 existing applications that I'd like to bridge somehow. Both have similar domains (Product Catalogs), but the first application uses a NoSQL document store for records, and the 2nd application uses SQL tables.

An example record from the first table looks something like:

```
{
  "productId": 123,
  "sku": "abc",
  "packageSizes": {
    "container": 20,
    "pallet": 50
  }
}
```

Whereas the same item in the 2nd domain would be 1 row in the `ProductItem` table:

```
| id  | sku |
| 123 | abc |
```

Then 2 rows in the `ProductPackageSizes` table:

```
| productId | type      | size |
| 123       | container | 20   |
| 123       | pallet    | 50   |
```

The systems currently are completely independent, but I'd like it so that whenever a record is created in the NoSQL application to have the same item created in the SQL application.

I can write a *one off* script for this, that just creates it procedurally based on what the data looks like currently. However, I would be interested to know if there are any established design patterns to describe such transformations? Particularly if there are new `packageSizes` or other relations added in the future.

Comment: depends on the end-purpose? just to replicate database schema between NoSQL and SQL. do-able, but why may i ask?

Comment: @user7568042 although the applications have some of the same types of data, they're not exactly the same. The first one has a slightly different purpose and is more under my control. Whereas the 2nd application (SQL) is a 3rd party reporting application that we happen to integrate with, but need to send the data into.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have any foreign keys in the sql database?

you can use a foreign key in `ProductPackageSizes` table that related with `ProductItem` and next in the every time that you want create a new record in the Nosql database you can assign

```
"productId": 123,"sku": "abc"
```

in the `ProductItem` , like :

`| id  | sku |
 | 123 | abc |`

and assign

```
"packageSizes": {
"container": 20,
"pallet": 50 }
```

to `ProductPackageSizes` with a foreign key (like P_id) , like :

`| productId | type      | size |P_id
 | 123       | container | 20   |123
 | 123       | pallet    | 50   |123`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: his example literally shows the FKs. The PK was committed for brevity.